# Python: How to store multiple values for one dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

I want to store a list of ingredients in a dictionary, using the ingredient name as the key and storing both the ingredient quantity and measurement as values. For example, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
ingredientList = {'flour' 500 grams, 'tomato' 10, 'mozzarella' 250 grams}
```

With the 'tomato' key, tomatoes do not have a measurement, only a quantity. Would I be able to achieve this in Python? Is there an alternate or more efficient way of going about this?

Comment: What's the input? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lists just use lists:

```
ingredientList = {'flour': [500,"grams"], 'tomato':[10], 'mozzarella' :[250, "grams"]}
```

To get the items:

```
weight ,meas = ingredientList['flour']
print(weight,meas)
(500, 'grams')
```

If you want to update just `ingredientList[key].append(item)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use another dict.

```
ingredientList = {
    'flour': {'quantity': 500, 'measurement': 'grams'},
    'tomato': {'quantity': 10},
    'mozzarella': {'quantity': 250, 'measurement': 'grams'}
}
```

Then you could access them like this:

```
print ingredientList['mozzarella']['quantity']
>>> 250
```